# PiranhaCMS - Get current Windows User

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, piranha-cms

In a brand new ASP.Net Core application you can select "Windows Authentication" and when you launch the app you directly have the Windows User and you can work with User.Identity in controllers.

I would like to get the Windows User in a PiranhaCMS MVC V10.0.0 app (by asking user crendentials if possible, automatically otherwise) and store it in the Piranha Users/Identity tables.

I tried to set the windowsAuthentication to true (in launchSettings.json) and add this in Startup.cs :

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate();
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

But User.Identity.Name is still null in controllers (until I log in in the manager with the default admin user).

How could I get the current Windows user by asking its (Windows or AD) credentials ?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to get the current user by adding the IIS Express settings and launching the corresponding profile in `launchSettings.json`.

I don’t know why it needed to launch IIS (to get the user) in PiranhaCMS and not in a new ASP.NET Core app.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": { // Here the section that was missing
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64223/",
      "sslPort": 44393
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "PiranhaCMS - Home": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:31005",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": { // Here the profile that needed to be added
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```